# Shared resources among Eclipse projects

Tags: java, eclipse, project

My team is developing different web applications using several common components and resources, so I suggested to create a shared jar project to contain common code and reference it as a jar.

But we also need to share resources like css, images and custom tags for jsp pages.

What's the common way to share these additional resources among Eclipse projects?

**NOTE** My main doubt is about custom tags, which are still under construction and at the moment changes must be replicated in each project...

Comment: You may publish all of them in a third party application and reference them from there. Then, this third party application may contain these resources in a CDN to speed up things.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree with you regarding images and css, but what about custom tags?

Comment: Handle them in a third party application as well, import them using a jar. Take a look here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/583489/JSP/java/Package-Custom-Tag-Library-Jar

Comment: This link might help you [sharing resources between different eclipse projects ?](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-19893.html) Thanks @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a library project and include this library project in two application projects.

Another approach is to create a Shared Source Folder, go to your project properties and in the Source tab, you can link a folder which may be in any other project and include all files of those folder as a link, without duplicating them.

(These two come from accepted answer to the other question)

A third approach is to create a common repository with all the shared files, that can be downloaded and imported into other projects.